# Python Lambda: Strings between length

Tags: python, lambda, filter

Given a list of Strings, print the list after omitting any words with lengths between 4 and 8 (inclusive).

I tried to this code:

```
 Question = filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 4 and len(x) >= 8, strs)
 print (list(Question))
```

but it returned this:

```
 []
```

Any ideas of how to do this without creating two different filter methods?

Comment: `problem_fiveone` is undefined.

Comment: it's working fine, print (list(Question ))

Comment: @ScottHunter: And `Question` is never used, so the `filter` is never involved.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It's still not working. Is my program outdated. I'm not sure what to do?

Comment: `strs` is undefined.

Comment: Are you *giving* it a single string?

Comment: @wwii . strs is defined as: [black, blue, green, purple, yellow, red]. but when I wrong the command, nothing is returned. it's empty.

Comment: `strs = ['hjkl','hjk','hjklasdf','hjklasdfg']; print(list(filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 8 and len(x) >= 4, strs)))` - works for me.

Comment: @DylanYoung the condition or predicate `len(x) <= 4 and len(x) >= 8` is never going to be true in any condition.
Either `len(x) <= 4` can be true or `len(x) >= 8` and you have used `AND` operator
between them.
I suppose based on your problem you should be using `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: `Question = filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 4 and len(x) <= 8, strs)` you have mis-places the less than and greater than symbol

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will retain elements according to predicate, not remove them. If you want to remove elemets with length 4 to 8, you should filter for reverse condition:

```
>>> strs = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'test_samples', 'sample_data']
>>> Question = filter(lambda x: len(x)> 8 or len(x) < 4, strs)
>>> list(Question)
['test_samples', 'sample_data']
```

Comment: Not very convincing test data.

Comment: If we're removing the strings with lengths between 8 and 4 inclusive, shouldn't it only print red?

Comment: @DylanYoung you are right, we have to take the other part. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Your test list:

```
In [81]: alist =  ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'red']
```

string lengths:

```
In [82]: [len(s) for s in alist]                                                               
Out[82]: [5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 3]
```

strings 4 or less - two found:

```
In [83]: [len(s)<=4 for s in alist]                                                            
Out[83]: [False, True, False, False, False, True]
```

strings 8 or more - none:

```
In [85]: [len(s)>=8 for s in alist]                                                            
Out[85]: [False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

both conditions at once - still none

```
In [86]: [len(s)<=4 and len(s)>=8 for s in alist]                                              
Out[86]: [False, False, False, False, False, False]

In [87]: q = filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 4 and len(x) >= 8, alist)                              
In [88]: list(q)                                                                               
Out[88]: []
```

`filter` passes elements that satisfy the condition, i.e. where Out[86] is True.  It works - given the test.

But you say you want to **omit** lengths between 4 and 8 inclusive:

Change the test to:
    In [92]: [len(s)>=4 and len(s)<=8 for s in alist]
    Out[92]: [True, True, True, True, True, False]

negate it:

```
In [93]: [not(len(s)>=4 and len(s)<=8) for s in alist]                                         
Out[93]: [False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

and alternative:

```
In [94]: [len(s)<4 or len(s)>8 for s in alist]                                                 
Out[94]: [False, False, False, False, False, True]

In [95]: list(filter(lambda s: len(s)<4 or len(s)>8, alist))                                   
Out[95]: ['red']
```

`filter` is **not** filter-out.

I like the clarity of a list comprehension like:

```
In [96]: [s for s in alist if len(s)<4 or len(s)>8]                                            
Out[96]: ['red']
```

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! this one: list(filter(lambda s: len(s)<4 or len(s)>8, alist))  worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

As per the problem statement

```
Given a list of Strings, print the list after omitting any words with lengths between 4 and 8 (inclusive)
```

The condition or predicate `len(x) <= 4 and len(x) >= 8` is never going to be true in any condition. Either `len(x) <= 4` can be true or `len(x) >= 8`.

logic should be something along the lines

```
In [1]: colors = [ 
    ...: 'White', 
    ...: 'Yellow', 
    ...: 'Blue', 
    ...: 'Red', 
    ...: 'Green', 
    ...: 'Black', 
    ...: 'Charcoal', 
    ...: 'Aquamarine', 
    ...: ] 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                                         

In [2]: result_colors = filter(lambda color: not (len(color) >= 4 and len(color) <= 8), colors)                                 

In [3]: list(result_colors)                                                                                                     
Out[3]: ['Red', 'Aquamarine']
```

By using De Morgan's laws condition 
`not (len(color) >= 4 and len(color) <= 8)` can be rewritten as `len(color) < 4 or len(color) > 8`.